# WPF Invokescript not supported?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, wpf

Iam trying to display somekind of help page in html within my wpf application and Ive loaded the html from my resourcers and it contains multiple javascript functions that i want to execute from c#.

This is how it should be done:

```
webBrowser1.InvokeScript("MyFunction");
```

This does not work at all, I get the error code:

```
Unknown name. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020006 (DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME))
```

Microsoft has no help regarding this and googling didn`t do the trick either.

**Question:** How do you invokescript in a wpf webbrowser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491132.aspx) -

> InvokeScript(String) should not be called before the document that implements
>   it has finished loading. You can detect when a document has finished loading by handling the LoadCompleted event.

This guy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636420/wpf-browser-invokescript) getting the same error and the reason is the one stated above i.e. trying to invoke before the document has been loaded.